# PHP from symbol to hex

Tags: php

I have a chinese character set as a variable with character encoding as utf-8:

```
$a='列';
```

From this, how can I get the value '5217' assigned to a string (`$b`) (possibly using UTF-16? but there might be a better way to do it)?

Codes:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5217/index.htm

Comment: I know you'd usually use `ord()` to get the ASCII code of a character, but in this case I don't know if it would work.

Comment: If it was ascii, I'd say to try `ord()`, but that obviously won't work here.

Comment: Can I convert from UTF-8 to ASCII somehow?

Comment: @David19801 - No.  UTF-8 represents a far far larger number of characters than ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function unicode_decode($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/((?:[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]{3})+)/", "decode_callback", $str);
}

function decode_callback($matches) {
    $char = mb_convert_encoding($matches[1], "UTF-16", "UTF-8");
    $escaped = "";
    for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($char); $i < $l; $i += 2) {
       $escaped .=  "\u" . sprintf("%02x%02x", ord($char[$i]), ord($char[$i+1]));
    }
    return $escaped;
}

$a='列';
var_dump(unicode_decode($a));
```

Comment: WORKS!  Needed to remove the "\u" part on $escaped to get the desired output...how does this even work...I don't know...

Comment: -1 This fails for the input `''` (`'\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'`) by returning `'\xa2'` (sic! not a number), and is needlessly hacky.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the UTF-8:

```
function utf8ord($c) {
  $ord0 = ord($c{0});
  if ($ord0 < 0x80) return $ord0;
  if ($ord0 < 0xe0) return ($ord0 & 0x1f) << 6  | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3f);
  if ($ord0 < 0xf0) return ($ord0 & 0x0f) << 12 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3f) << 6 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3f);
  return ($ord0 & 0x07) << 18 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3f) << 12 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3f) << 6 | (ord($c{3}) & 0x3f);
}

$a = '列';
$b = dechex(utf8ord($a));
var_export($b); // outputs '5217'
```

Comment: @xdazz Oops, had a typo in there. Fixed.